# Bootstrap carousel control links generating error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, smarty, carousel

I have a Twitter Bootstrap carousel running on a site. The code for the carousel is generated using Smarty templates. I have tons of other carousels running using the same code, but something about this one is causing me grief. The images are rotating just fine, but I get an error when I click on one of the controls that advance the carousel. Here's the error I am getting in Firebug:

```
TypeError: $active.attr(...) is undefined   
, curId = $active.attr('id').substring(7) (bootstrap.js, line 343)
```

(Chrome throws a warning about substring being undefined for an undefined element)

In case you don't have a copy handy, here is the relevant section of bootstrap.js:

```
, slide: function (type, next) {
var $active = this.$element.find('.item.active')
, $next = next || $active[type]()
, isCycling = this.interval
, direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
, fallback = type == 'next' ? 'first' : 'last'
, that = this
, e = $.Event('slide', {
relatedTarget: $next[0]
})
, curId = $active.attr('id').substring(7)
```

It seems that the most likely cause of this error is that none of the .item elements (the carousel images) is currently .active. Or that the active carousel element doesn't have an ID. But I can tell by watching the code in Firebug that neither of these things are happening.

In case it helps, here is the Smarty code that generates the carousel controls, showing that each element has an ID, and that the first element is being assigned a class of .active:

```
<div class="text-control">
            {foreach from=$articles item=article name=artforeach}
                <a {if $article.source|strlen > 7}href="{$article.source}"{else}href="javascript:void(0)"{/if} 
                    {if $smarty.foreach.artforeach.first} class="active"{/if} id="name{$article.id}" 
                    data-target="{$smarty.foreach.artforeach.index}">
                    <h3>{$article.name}</h3>
                    <p>{$article.teaser[0].content|strip_tags|truncate:100:"..."}</p>
                </a>
            {/foreach}
        </div>
```

Anybody have a clue as to what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of trying different things and examining code, I figured out that the problem was related to the concept of "event bubbling". Although the .active class, the ID, and the data-target are all applied to the a element, the click event is actually handled by the h3 element inside the a element. And since the h3 doesn't have class .active or an ID or a data-target, the carousel broke down. I thought maybe it had to do with the special block-level status of the h3 element, but this also happens if you put a span element or an i element in there.

This code works:

```
<div class="text-control">
            {foreach from=$articles item=article name=artforeach}
                <a {if $article.source|strlen > 7}href="{$article.source}"{else}href="javascript:void(0)"{/if} 
                    {if $smarty.foreach.artforeach.first} class="active"{/if} id="name{$article.id}" 
                    data-target="{$smarty.foreach.artforeach.index}">
                    {$article.name}
                    <p>{$article.teaser[0].content|strip_tags|truncate:100:"..."}</p>
                </a>
            {/foreach}
        </div>
```

All I've done is remove the h3 tags. Interestingly, the p tags don't seem to affect the event bubbling at all. As long as there is plain text at the beginning of the a element, everything else seems to be fine.